# Synology simple script strange behaviour

Tags: linux, sh, ascii, synology

Im triying to run a very simple script in a Synology (linux based NAS) for replacing all the "Ñ" characters in my files:

```
find $path -depth -type d -name '*\Ñ*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\Ñ/}"' _ {} \;
```

If I run this command by ssh in the terminal, everything goes well, but if I run the .sh file containing this command, the "Ñ" character is not recognized. I know that because if I change the letter "Ñ" by any other one the script works, and because writing "echo Ñ" in the sh doenst return a good character (gives the typical not recognized symbol [?]) and in the terminal making echo works well.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your .sh file properly save in UTF-8 encoding? To check, check what you see as the output of `file /path/to/your/sh/file`. If it says the file contains only ASCII text, then your file isn't saving with the correct encoding. Also, I believe your question should not be tagged as `ascii`, it should be tagged as a Unicode question.